# Turan number of cycles of length at most $2k$ for $k\geq 2$.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics, extremal-graph-theory

> **Theorem** (short even cycles)
>
> For any integer $k\geq 2$, we have
> $\text{ex}(n,\{C_4,\dots,C_{2k}\})=O_k(n^{1+1/k}).$

*Remark:* $\text{ex}(n,\{C_4,\dots,C_{2k}\})$ is the maximal number of edges in the $n$-vertex graph which does not contains an even cycle of length at most $2k$.

To prove this theorem we need the following two technical lemmas.

> **Lemma 1** (Large bipartite subgraph)
>
> Every $G$ has a bipartite subgraph with at least $e(G)/2$ edges.

> **Lemma 2** (Large average degree implies subgraph with large minimum degree)
>
> Let $t>0$. Every graph with average degree $2t$ has a
> subgraph with minimum degree greater than $t$.

*Proof of Theorem.* Suppose that the graph $G$ is the maximizer, i.e. $\text{ex}(n,\{C_4,\dots,C_{2k}\})=e(G)$. Applying Lemma 1, we find a bipartite subgraph $G'$ of $G$ such that $e(G')\geq \dfrac{e(G)}{2}$. Now applying Lemma 2, we find a subgraph $G''$ of $G'$ such that $$\delta(G'')>\underbrace{\dfrac{d_{\text{ave}}(G')}{2}}_{=t}=\dfrac{e(G')}{\nu(G')}\geq\dfrac{e(G)}{2\nu(G)}.$$

Notice that $G''$ is a bipartite subgraph of $G'$ (and hence of $G$) with $\delta(G'')>t\geq\dfrac{e(G)}{2\nu(G)}$.

Let $u$ be an arbitrary vertex of $G''$. For each $i=0,1,\dots,k$, let $A_i$ denote the set of vertices at distance exactly $i$ from $u$.

[image]

For each $i=1,\dots,k-1$, every vertex of $A_i$ has:

- no neighbors in $A_i$ (or else $G''$ would not be bipartite),
- exactly one neighbor in $A_{i-1}$ (else we can backtrace through two neighbours which must converge at some point to form an even cycle of length at most $2k$),
- and thus $>t-1$ neighbors in $A_{i+1}$ (by the minimum degree assumption on $G''$).

Therefore, each layer $A_i$ expands to the next by a factor at least $t-1$. Hence
$$\nu(G)\geq |A_k|\geq (t-1)^k\geq \left(\frac{e(G)}{2\nu(G)}-1\right)^k.$$
And thus $$e(G)\leq 2\nu(G)^{1+1/k}+2\nu(G).$$

I understand the idea of the proof but there are some technical moments which I did not understand:

**Questions.**

1. "*every vertex of $A_i$ has no neighbors in $A_i$*". Am I right that if this happens then we have an odd cycle in bipartite graph $G''$ which is absurd?
2. Here $A_1$ is basically the neighbors of $u$, i.e. $N(u)$ which exists because $|A_1|=\deg(u)\geq \delta(G'')>t>0$ and hence $|A_1|\geq 1$. But how do we know that $A_2,\dots, A_k$ exist? I think that it follows if $t>1$ but I cannot prove that $t>1$.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Isn't it a bit inconsistent to use $\nu(G)$ for the number of vertices and $e(G)$ for the number of edges? Some people write Latin letters for both ($v(G)$ and $e(G)$), and some people write Greek letters for both ($\nu(G)$ and $\epsilon(G)$), but I've never seen anyone mix the two. (More on the notation [here](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~west/igt/notat.html).)

Comment: @MishaLavrov, Hmm very interesting! Most of the questions which I am asking they are from Yufei Zhao's book "Graph Theory and Additive Combinatorics" and he uses the notation $e(G)$ and $\nu(G)$. However, I am also reading the book of Reinhard Diestel and he uses the notations $|G|$ and $\lVert G\rVert$ for the number of vertices and edges, respectively. To be honest, I personally like $e(G)$ and $\nu(G)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First question.** Yes: whenever there is an edge between $v,w \in A_i$, this creates an odd cycle. There is some largest $j<i$ (possibly $j=0$, possibly not) such that $v$ and $w$ have a common ancestor in $A_j$; going from $v$ back to that ancestor, forward to $w$, and then directly to $v$ is a cycle of length $2(i-j)+1$.

**Second question.** We cannot guarantee $t>1$ just from assuming that $G$ does not have an even cycle of length $2k$ or shorter. But remember: our goal is to prove that $G$ can't have too many edges, and having $t\le 1$ should help us with that.

If $t \le 1$, that means $G'$ has average degree at most $2t \le 2$, so $e(G') \le v(G')$, and therefore $e(G) \le 2 v(G)$. If $t>1$, you can proceed with your proof and obtain $e(G) \le 2v(G)^{1+1/k} + 2v(G)$. So the weaker of these two bounds, $e(G) \le 2v(G)^{1+1/k} + 2v(G)$, holds no matter what $t$ is.

Comment: It makes sense now! But after some deep thoughts I am confused how to prove rigorously that each $A_i$ is nonempty.

Comment: Well, if a vertex in $A_i$ has at least $t-1$ neighbors in $A_{i+1}$, and $t-1 > 0$, that means $A_{i+1}$ is nonempty.

Comment: Yes, but in order to prove that a vertex in $A_i$ has at least $t-1$ neighbors in $A_{i+1}$ we rely on the fact that $A_i\neq \varnothing$.

Comment: Induct! You know that $A_0 \ne \varnothing$.

Comment: Yeah now it makes sense (that was a stupid question actually on my side). Thank you for your help, Misha! +1